# Why doesn't my string reversal my_str[len(my_str)-1:-1:-1] produce output?

Tags: python

**TL;DR:** Why doesn't `my_str[6:-1:-1]` work while `my_str[6::-1]` does?

I have a string:

```py
my_str="abcdefg"
```

I have to reverse parts of the string, which I generally do with

```py
my_str[highest_included_index:lowest_included_index-1:-1]
```

For example,

```py
# returns the reverse of all values between indices 2 and 6 (inclusive)
my_str[6:2-1:-1]
'gfedc'
```

This pattern breaks down if I want to include the 0 index in my reversal:

```py
my_str[6:0-1:-1]  # does NOT work
''
my_str[6:-1:-1]   # also does NOT work
''
my_str[6::-1]     # works as expected
'gfedcba'
```

Do I have to add an edge case that checks if the lowest index I want to include in a reversed string is zero and not include it in my reversal? I.e., do I have to do

```py
for low in range(0,5):
    if low == 0:
        my_str[6::-1]
    else:
        my_str[6:low-1:-1]
```

That seems... unwieldy and not what I expect from python.

Edit:

The closest thing I could find to documentation of this is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

> `s[i:j:k]`
> ...
> The slice of s from i to j with step k is defined as the sequence of items with index `x = i + n*k` such that `0 <= n < (j-i)/k`. In other words, the indices are `i`, `i+k`, `i+2*k`, `i+3*k` and so on, stopping when j is reached (but never including j). When k is positive, i and j are reduced to `len(s)` if they are greater. When k is negative, i and j are reduced to `len(s) - 1` if they are greater. If i or j are omitted or `None`, they become “end” values (which end depends on the sign of k). Note, k cannot be zero. If k is `None`, it is treated like 1.

However, this mentions nothing about a negative j being maximized to zero, which it appears is the current behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_str[6:0-1:-1]  # does NOT work
''
my_str[6:-1:-1]   # also does NOT work
''
```

Yes, they *do* work -- as documented.  A negative index is the sequence position, counting from the right.  These expressions are equivalent to

```
my_str[6:-1:-1]
```

Since `6` and `-1` denote the same position, the result is an empty string.  However, if you give a value that is at or past the string start, such as

```
my_str[6:-10:-1]
```

then you see the expected reversal, just as if you'd specified `6::-1`

Yes, you have to make a special case for the discontinuity in indexing.

Comment: So I should just think of this as `-1 := len(my_sequence) - 1` whenever dealing with sequences?

Comment: Yes, that's the easy way.  -2 is the next one "to the left" and so on.  This is included in any tutorial on sequences.

Answer (score 1):

```
#something like this?
x='my test string'
print(x[3:7][::-1])
```

Comment: While this works, the OP was asking *why* their particular solution does not work.

Comment: This is the best way I've seen to get around this particular issue, so while it does not answer the question, I think it is worth mentioning to others trying to understand how to avoid the problem I had.